# How to apply javascript to all Tumblr posts in main feed instead of just most recent post

Tags: javascript, tumblr

JS total noob here.

I'm trying to apply this code inside tumblr theme file but it's only getting applied to the most recent post in the main feed. This is to show comment count for disqus but using {sourcelurl}

```
{block:ContentSource}
<a href="{permalink}" id="disqus-comment-count">0</a>Comments
<script>
let sourceurl = '{sourceurl}'
var disqusVar = sourceurl.replace("https://href.li/?","") + '#disqus_thread';
$("#disqus-comment-count").attr("data-disqus-url", disqusVar);
</script>
{/block:ContentSource}
```

For those wondering, the script needs to be wrapped inside {block:ContentSource}{/block:ContentSource} for {sourceurl} variable to work.

Any idea why this might be?

Comment: It is tricky to tell from this example if you could make a jsfiddle or similar, and/or link to your blog. I guess you want to repeat this block under every post? In which case `$("#disqus-comment-count")` should be unique as it is using an ID. There will be a way to reference each post count using .`closest()` or something similar. If you are outputting this under every post what is `'{sourceurl}'` evaluated to? Is it different for each post?

Comment: @lharby Thanks for your response.

Link to example blog. 
[link](https://toastycinnamonqueen.tumblr.com/)

{sourceurl} is supposed to output the link in Tumblr post's Content Source field when you create a post, which connects it to the Disqus thread's URL. So yes, you are correct, it's different for each post.

The comment counts do seem to work  inside the post themselves, just not on the main feed page where it only applies to the first post.

Comment: Yeah a couple of issues here, you declare `sourceurl` with a let, which works for the first iteration, but later you are trying to reset the let (usually you would do `let sourceurl = someVar`, then later `sourceurl = anotherVar` (without the let). The other issue is that `#disqus-comment-count` is an ID, so jQuery will only expect it once in the dom. There is a way to loop through ids, using .attr() however it would be better if you can change the disqus href to a classname. If you can put the whole tumblr theme in pastebin I might be able to have a go. See: https://imgur.com/a/nRJcqyg

Comment: @lharby Ah, the duplicate var and ID being unique makes sense now that you point it out. So in theory, a different looping would be needed for the feed (not inside the post)? Inside post currently works which is fine.

Here's the whole html of tumblr. [link] (https://pastebin.com/SQ8s5pxV)

Comment: @lharby Another angle could be putting data-disqus-url in the href, seems to work as far as outputting the unique sourceurl for every post.
```<a href="{permalink}" id="disqus-comment-count" data-disqus-url="{sourceurl}">0</a>
```
But there still needs to be JS (loop?) for the removal of href.li in the url (which is a tumblr thing). That's what the .replace is for.

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Hi did you manage to fix this. I see some new code in your theme. I have installed the code on a test tumblr, I had to activate a disqus account, plus I have no comments, so I cannot see the output. Also it seems you have two similar functions firing for this code. Are both necessary? I am wondering if I can use your disqus shortname?